# How can I use more than 50% of the CPU when converting image sequences?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

When I wanna convert a sequence of images into a movie file, only 50% of the cpu are getting used. How can I increase this number and accelerate the whole process?

Comment: Are you running a dual core CPU? If so, the 50% are the maximum you can get. The sequencer doesn't support multi threading or GPU acceleration, yet.

Comment: I have a i5 quad core.. ok that answers my question. Multithreading would be nice

Comment: Most likely your Harddisk won't let you read in more data at once...